# Repeated rows being selected in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am making an app with a dynamic table and when I load all of the values in my table and run the app, I will select a row with a checkmark and scroll down and see that another row beneath it is also selected with a checkmark. However, it is not adding the data from that other row to my data, it is still showing as checked.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath)
    // let genresFromLibrary = genrequery.collections
    let rowitem = genresFromLibrary![indexPath.row].representativeItem
    cell.textLabel?.text = rowitem?.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyGenre) as? String

    // Configure the cell...
    // cell.textLabel?.text =

    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let rowitem = genresFromLibrary![indexPath.row].representativeItem
    print(rowitem?.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyGenre) as! String)
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .checkmark//places the checkmark

    GenresWanted.append(rowitem!)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)?.accessoryType = .none
    ///we want to delete it from the array here
    let rowitem = genresFromLibrary![indexPath.row].representativeItem
    print("Removed: \(rowitem?.value(forProperty: MPMediaItemPropertyGenre) as! String)")
    if let index = GenresWanted.index(of: rowitem!)
    {
        GenresWanted.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

Above is my code. I think it might have to do with the cellforRowAt, but I am not sure.

Comment: You need to show your complete `cellForRowAt`. You've left out the important part - how you set the cell's `accessoryType`.

Comment: Cells are reused. When you change the state of an UI element outside of `cellForRowAt` the cell might be reused with this change. The recommended way is to keep the *selected* state in the model and set it in `cellForRow` accordingly. In `did(De)SelectRowAt` update the value in the model and reload the row. By the way: Why is the data source array (`genresFromLibrary`) an optional?

Comment: @Sh_Khan's answer should do the trick. The key to remember is always use else part when you dequeue the cells.

Answer (score 1):

The problem behind that is cell re-using so you should make it `.none` in `cellForRow`

```
var selected:IndexPath

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath)

  if(selected.row == indexPath.row)
  {
     cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
  }
  else
  {
     cell.accessoryType = .none
  }


 }

 override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      selected = indexPath
      // here reload the cell at that indexPath
 }
```

Comment: I did this but now when I select the rows and the checkmarks appear, I will scroll down and back up and the rows won't have checkmarks on them anymore..

Comment: what if i want to select multiple rows? would I just keep track with a global array?

Comment: yes ................go on with that , append in didSelect , remove in didDeselect and reload

Comment: That worked very well. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

You should do it in your table view cell class like;

```
class YourTableViewCell:UITableViewCell {
    //This method is called when you select/deselect the cell and also when you reuse a cell
    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        self.accessoryType  = selected ? .checkmark : .none;
    } 

    // ... Your code
}
```

and remove the accessory type logic from your didSelect/didDeselect method;

**Note:** If there is no class is attached from your table view cell, you should really do so to manage your logic.